# how to return from static void to another static void

Tags: c#

i want to return from private static void IfType() to static void Main(string[] args) is there any way to return because when i try to return to a label it says the name help does not exist in current context so i tryed to search up a fix for it but i didnt found anything that helps so im asking now

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace help
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           help:
       }

       private static void IfType()
       {
           {
               ConsoleKeyInfo IfType = Console.ReadKey();
               {
                   if (IfType.KeyChar == '1')
                   {
                   }
                   if (IfType.KeyChar == '2')
                   {
                      return help;
                   }
                   if (IfType.KeyChar == '3')
                   {
                   }
                   if (IfType.KeyChar == '4')
                   {
                   }
                   if (IfType.KeyChar == '5')
                   {
                   }
                   if (IfType.KeyChar == '6')
                   {
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: instead of jumping accross your code, you should create methods for your tasks, e.g. displaing a help-message, perform a db-query or whatever. Then just call the appropriate method, e.g. `DisplayHelp`.

Comment: If you want to return something than do not declare the method VOID.

Comment: Or you can do what you want with the returning value in your `IfType` method. If you would like to define the method as VOID.